# Couldn't open CUDA library libcupti.so.8.0

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tensorflow

When I try to start my tensorflow-gpu 1.3 project, I get these errors:

```
Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 980, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0)
2017-10-09 11:47:48.575276: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1032] Ignoring gpu device (device: 1, name: GeForce GT 730, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0) with Cuda multiprocessor count: 2. The minimum required count is 8. You can adjust this requirement with the env var TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT.
2017-10-09 11:47:48.920420: I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:129] Couldn't open CUDA library libcupti.so.8.0. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
2017-10-09 11:47:48.920452: F ./tensorflow/stream_executor/lib/statusor.h:212] Non-OK-status: status_ status: Failed precondition: could not dlopen DSO: libcupti.so.8.0; dlerror: libcupti.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Most threads refer to .bashrc linking the library correctly:

```
# added by Anaconda2 4.4.0 installer
export PATH="/home/user/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

I think that my links in the .bashrc are correct. I already tried to reinstall with `sudo apt-get install libcuda1-384`

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8830 The lib is not in `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`, but another cuda lib dir.

Comment: thanks that helped